# Rotation with the limit in unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I am building an application in unity.
when User click on an GameObject the model position is changed.
Now I need is on change of the position, Rotation is also changed with the limit axis/Co-ordination point.

Here is my code change of the position on input click of the gameObject.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class centertheroombox : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject box345;
    public int speed = 1;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000.0f))
                {
                    if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Box345")
                    {
                        Debug.Log("yupiee pressed");                    
                        box345.transform.position = new Vector3(3, 0, -9);

                        //box345.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, Time.deltaTime);
                        //box345.transform.Rotate = new Vector3(353,0,0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to know?  If you want to limit the rotation, you can use the Mathf.Clamp(value, min, max) function...

Comment: @Savlon clamping a rotation isn't quite that straightforward since the euler representations are circular, -90 and +270 are the same, so greaterthan/lessthan computations tend to get messy. There are many ways to get around this though. One of my preferred methods is to get the `angle` between a given axis and the transform.forward and clamp that (`angle` returned is always acute so you don't have the same problem as with raw rotations), there are many more methods and it's a common question on the unity answers and scripting forums

Comment: @Savlon Thanks can you please tell how to use max and min function as i am new to unity

Comment: The max and min part of the function is where you place the maximum value and minimum value you want your value to stay between.